# Finding an item in a repeater control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This one might be simple, but here it is anyway.

I have a `List<Object>` that I bind to a repeater. The repeater binds all of the fields to textboxes ***except `Id`***. In my web page, whenever a user adds a new item, I create a new `Object` in my list with a unique `Id` and rebind my repeater.

At a certain point in my code, I am trying to read the textbox controls from the repeater and put them into my `List<Object>`. However, I need access to the `Id` field to know which List item to insert into. How can I get the specific `Id` while I'm going through the repeater?

I know I can just create a hidden field with the Id in the repeater control and get it that way, but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Example:

```
if (DependentRptr.Items.Count > 0)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < DependentRptr.Items.Count; count++)
    {
        int did = (form.UserId + (count + 1)); //I'm trying to get the id of this field here.
        ...get control info...

        var temp = AddedDependents.ToList().Find(p => p.Id == did); //here is where I search with the id
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let us see how you bind the repeater and also the html to see the how you create the textboxes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Repeater` is actually considered as a *read-only* control.

It is one of the simplest built-in data-bound controls.

It does not support actions like editing, inserting, deleting *out of the box*. If you want to use one of these actions in a repeater, you would have to write custom code to accomplish it. Even paging and sorting is not supported out of the box using a `Repeater`.

Therefore, there's no better way to accomplish your requirement while using a `Repeater` control, so a `HiddenField` would be a good way to fulfill your requirement.

However depending on your specific needs, you should consider using another data-bound control.

For example, the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) control **is also based on templates like the `Repeater`** but it also supports common actions like editing, inserting and deleting

A `ListView` control contains the `DataKeyNames` property used to keep track of the ID's of each row